# Subtracting 1 ISO 8601 year from a date in BigQuery

Tags: date, google-bigquery, iso

I'm trying to manipulate a date value to go back in time exactly 1 ISO-8601 year.
The following does not work, but best describes what I want to accomplish:

```
date_add(date '2018-01-03', interval -1 isoyear)
```

I tried string conversion as an intermediate step, but that doesn't work either:

```
select parse_date('%G%V%u',safe_cast(safe_cast(format_date('%G%V%u',date '2018-01-03') as int64)-1000 as string))
```

The error provided for the last one is "Failed to parse input string "2017013"". I don't understand why, this should always resolve to a unique date value.

Is there another way in which I can subtract an ISO year from a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the corresponding day of the previous ISO year by subtracting the appropriate number of weeks from the date. I based the calculation on the description of [weeks per year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_year) from the Wikipedia page:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION IsLongYear(d DATE) AS (
  -- Year starting on Thursday
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE_TRUNC(d, YEAR)) = 5 OR
  -- Leap year starting on Wednesday
  (EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d), 2, 28), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 29
   AND EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE_TRUNC(d, YEAR)) = 4)
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION PreviousIsoYear(d DATE) AS (
  DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL IF(IsLongYear(d), 53, 52) WEEK)
);

SELECT PreviousIsoYear('2018-01-03');
```

This returns `2017-01-04`, which is the third day of the 2017 ISO year. `2018-01-03` is the third day of the 2018 ISO year.

Comment: It's checking if the current year has 53 weeks, but shouldn't it check the previous year? Also, I'm not sure what should happen if the input week number is week 53...

Comment: It depends on what you want :) You can probably adapt this answer to subtract the number of weeks in the previous year instead if that gives you the desired output.

Comment: I got it with IF( EXTRACT(isoyear from DATE_TRUNC(d, year))) = EXTRACT(year from d)), 53, 52)Thanks!